# How to watch all data in a vue.js application?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using localStorage to persist my vue.js application data between page loads.  I'm following [this tutorial](https://travishorn.com/add-localstorage-to-your-vue-app-in-2-lines-of-code-56eb2c9f371b), and so far things are working well.  My app looks like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#content',
  data: {
      persistant: {
          plan: 'Mega',
          seats: '0',
          support_plan: 'None'
      },
  },
  watch: {
      persistant: {
          handler() {
              localStorage.setItem('service_plan_wizard', JSON.stringify(this.persistant));
              console.log('saving items');
          },
          deep: true
      },
```

As you can see, whenever anything changes in the "persistant" portion of the data, it gets saved to localStorage.  Pretty cool.

However, nesting all of the data within the "persistant" block is causing problems elsewhere.  For example, using *compute* on a nested value doesn't work.

Is it possible to watch *all* data in a view?  I'm looking for something like:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#content',
  data: {
      plan: 'Mega',
      seats: '0',
      support_plan: 'None'
  },
  watch: {
  data: {
      handler() {
          localStorage.setItem('service_plan_wizard', JSON.stringify(this.data));
          console.log('saving items');
      },
      deep: true
  },
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're just going to watch all of your data and trigger actions on any update anywhere, then why not just use the `updated` lifecycle hook?

Comment: That's a great idea.  I'm going to try it out and see if there are any issues. For other wanderers such as myself, here's more information about the `updated` lifecycle hook: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated